# How to integrate Oracle APEX with attendance fingerprint

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

How to integrate Oracle APEX with attendance fingerprint ??
I have Oracle DB 18c and Oracle APEX 19.1 , I need to integrate my APEX application with attendance fingerprint , To get a specified data for all users those print their fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works here, where I work:

- fingerprint device sends data into an Oracle database

  - I don't know whether you can do that yourself, or should it be done by a representative of the company that sold you the device
- once data is in the database, the rest is easy

  - if Apex is installed in the same database that contains attendance data, just let your workspsace *see* that schema
  - if not, use a database link to access attendance data and create a view in your schema which will show that data

    - note that you might need to properly tune your queries because - for the first several days/weeks/months, when there's not that many data, everything will work smoothly. But, with *zillions* of rows, things tend to slow down
    - a materialized view might be faster in such a case, but - expect certain delay, i.e. you won't see someone's data *immediately*